# Spring MVC Server-Side Message Listener, Client Side update with WebSockets

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, broker

I am quite new with Spring MVC and Web technologies.

I need "real time" interactions between the server side and the client side of my web application.
When a user click on a button, I want to execute server side code, create a message and send it to every client.

I think Web Sockets are the solution. I can add methods on the controller part of my application.
When a user click on a button, the Controller method is called. I can execute code and send back a message for every clients.

But now, I can receive messages coming from another website. Let's say that I am using a MessageListener.

How am I supposed to notify my clients? The server side of WebSockets is in the controller. I don't think i am supposed to call this method from the server.

I can create some kind of weird adapter capable to
 - Establish WebSocket channel with server (a local channel)
 - Receive messages from another website using a broker
 - Send the message to the controller

I don't feel like this is an unusual need and my solution looks tricky.
I am sure there is an easier way to do it, but I am not able to find it.

So, am I doing it right? Do you have any idea, any suggestion?

Thank you for your help.

Ben